# Optimise LEFT JOIN in PostgreSQL (PGAdmin4)

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL one of which is 16 million rows and the other is around 3000. They both share 2 common IDs, but the larger table has thousands of iterations of the same ID.

I'm trying to do a LEFT JOIN with a few conditions as follows:

```
SELECT LT.Col1, LT.Col2, LT.Col3, ST.Col1, ST.Col2
FROM large_table as LT
LEFT JOIN small_table as ST
ON LT.id1 = ST.id1 AND LT.id2 = ST.id2
WHERE LT.Col1 > 30
AND LT.Col2 > 2
AND LT.Col3 BETWEEN '11:00:00'::time AND '21:00:00'::time
```

I have created multi-column Indexes based on id1 and id2 for each table, but the query is just running and running. Using PGAdmin4 on a macbook pro 16gb RAM, 2.9ghz quad core i7. I've checked the computer performance and it's not struggling. Does anybody have any advice on how to speed up the query? Am I just asking too much of it?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Add an index on your time column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a left outer join, your best bet is to use indexes on `large_table` that reduces the number of rows early on.

Unfortunately none of your conditions checks for equality, so a combined index is useless.

You could create indexes on the three columns of `large_table` and see if PostgreSQL uses them (e.g. using a bitmap inex scan and combining the results).

Those indexes that PostgreSQL chooses not to use can be dropped again.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating combined index for tuple (id1, id2) in both tables. Then use `ON (LT.id1, LT.id2) = (ST.id1, ST.id2)`

Comment: `ON LT.id1 = ST.id1 AND LT.id2 = ST.id2` will be treated the same way by the optimizer as `ON (LT.id1, LT.id2) = (ST.id1, ST.id2)` - and according to RicHep there are already "multi-column indexes" on id1 and id2